# How to specify specific css/js to include in Webpack?

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core

I've started an .Net Core with Angular 2 project. Webpack and everything are quite new to me but I'm starting to understand them.

I've created a project with `dotnet new angular`, and I've understood how I can populate the `webpack.config.vendor.js` to reference my nugets packages.

I've now some CSS/JS that I want to include directly(There is no nuget packages with them)(don't know where to put hem, currently they are in `/libs/somefolder/something.js/.css`

So I tried to put in the `entry: {vendor:[]}` array(`webpack.config.vendor.js`) two new entry:

```
entry: {
    vendor: [
        //Previous entries
        '/libs/somefolder/something.js',
        '/libs/somefolder/something.css',
    ]
},
```

But when I run  `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js`, I get error:

> ERROR in dll vendor Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   '/libs/somefolder/something.js' in 'E:\My\Project.Web'  @ dll vendor
>
> ERROR in dll vendor Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   '/libs/somefolder/something.css' in 'E:\My\Project.Web'  @ dll vendor

So, how should I reference those?

Comment: Have you tried adding `modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "libs"), "node_modules"]` inside the `resolve: {}` config, then specifying those extra libraries as `somefolder/something.js`? See [resolve.modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules)

Comment: @DanielJ.G. That was the solution. Could you transform your comment into an answer?

Comment: Please avoid using "tag: title" format in future and either remove the tag completely or put it in a more organic/natural way into the title itself. Read this help center article on how to correctly use tags http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: @Tseng I was finding this better to understand the context of the question. There is many places where the tags are not present and you can't even find the main topic

Comment: Like I said, it's okay when you use it in an "organic/natural" way, see my edit ;) but just stuffing tags into title is frowned upon, because it becomes hard to read and doesn't summarize the problem: ".net core - mvc - not working" is a bad title, as it tells nothing about the problem and just has a bunch of tags. tag section is sufficient in most needs, because most people don't look at the front page but monitor specific tags they are interested in, i.e. i'm monitoring asp.net-core tag and mvvm, so we see the question if they are properly tagged, no need to stuff it in the title

Answer (score 0):

Tell webpack how to find your extra libraries using its [resolve.modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) configuration property. This way it will be able to find your custom libraries placed inside `libs` and not just the ones inside node_modules.

Your [`webpack.config.vendor.js`](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/dev/templates/Angular2Spa/webpack.config.vendor.js) configuration might look similar to this:

```
...
resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.js' ],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "libs"), "node_modules"]
}
entry: {
    vendor: [
        //Previous entries
        '/libs/somefolder/something.js',
        '/libs/somefolder/something.css',
    ]
},
...
```